# Center element without knowing its width

Tags: html, width, center

I have a menu element like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubItem 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubItem 3</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

The element is positioned absolutely. How can I center it without knowing its width (number of parent elements might change).

Regards, 
Dave

Comment: Centre which element? The parent UL? Centre it in relation to what? The screen? The parent? The universe?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're after is possible if you have a parent element to the ul:

```
<div class="example">
   <ul> 
     <!-- lots of li's -->
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Then use the old school text-align trick that was used to center layouts:

```
.example {
   text-align: center;
   }

.example ul {
   text-align: left;
   display: inline-block;
   }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/chippper/WK5Z4/